# How do I access Font Stylistic Sets in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I access Stylistic Sets in Adobe Illustrator.

For example this font. Which I have installed has Stylistic sets:
http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/debi-sementelli/cantoni/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could vary quite considerably depending on the version of Illustrator you're using.  In Illustrator CS6 (I'm afraid that I don't have other versions with which to test), you can access your OpenType Stylistic Alternates by;

1. Selecting your text (with appropriate font selected)
2. Open the OpenType window by going to WINDOW > TYPE > OPENTYPE

[image: Stylistic Alternates]

Here you should see numerous options - many of which may or may not be available, depending on your font - but amongst which are 'Stylistic Alternates', 'Swash' and 'Contextual Alternates', etc.

If you want to **view** the various characters (rather than switching settings), you might more usefully go to WINDOW > TYPE > GLYPHS.  You can then use the 'Show' dropdown box to see a visual grid of all the characters the font provides.

[image: Glyphs]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Now I need to buy that font.